# JQuery - changing a table cell's color if it contains a number from array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to change the background color of all table cells that contain a number from array with duplicates. The idea is to make all cells with duplicate numbers red.
So far I've managed to change the color but it also changes the colors of the empty cells.

I tried checking if the number is undefined, 'undefined', null, 0 but it still changes the colors of the empty cells.

```js
$('#resetPoolsButton').on('click', function() {
  var seedNums = []
  $('.seedInputs').each(function(i, seedInputs) {

    seedNums.push($(seedInputs).val())
  })
  seedNums.sort()

  var duplicates = []
  for (var i = 0; i <= seedNums.length; i++) {

    if (seedNums[i] === seedNums[i + 1] && seedNums[i] !== 'undefined') {

      duplicates.push(seedNums[i])

      $('.seedInputs').filter(function(i, element) {
        return duplicates.includes($(element).val())
      }).css("background-color", "red");
      console.log($(this).val())
    }
  }

  console.log(duplicates)
})
```

Comment: Please post a working code snippet demonstrating your problem.

Comment: Please update the snippet I made with relevant HTML creating a [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

Based on

> So far I've managed to change the color but it also changes the colors
>   of the empty cells.

and

> I tried checking if the number is undefined, 'undefined', null, 0 but
>   it still changes the colors of the empty cells.

You need to check if the `$(element).val()` is empty or not. Change your `filter` to

```
  $('.seedInputs').filter(function(i, element) {
    return $(element).val().trim().length > 0 && duplicates.includes($(element).val())
  }).css("background-color", "red");
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch, that fixed it! Can you please explain to me why my approach was wrong. I thought that if check if the duplicates are undefined would also work ? Cheers

Comment: You were checking `undefined` in the array, not in the cell value.

Comment: Yes but if it does not go into the array, how can I filter by it ?

Comment: Not sure where is the confusion. You need to filter empty cells, not the empty values in the array.

Comment: Yes but the function checks if the cells have values equal to the values in the array. If the array doesn't have the 0/null values, wouldn't it work ?

Comment: You are confusing `0/null/undefined` with `""` (empty).

Comment: Ah! So there's the problem! So if it was seedNums[i] != "" it would have worked ?

Comment: @TreantFotwenty Try the same. Unless you can share a working code (with error reproducible), it is difficult for me to verify.